# Pick list elements from inside dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to iterate over the lists inside the dictionary below and **return the elements that are not inside both of the lists**.

```
{'ABC-01': ['aaa',
            'bbb',
            'ccc',
            'ddd'],
 'ABC-02': ['aaa',
            'bbb',
            'ccc',
            'eee']}
```

It would then return something like:

```
ABC-01 contains ddd
ABC-02 contains eee
```

I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set xor (^ = find all items unique in some set) and then set intersection (& = find all items that overlap between sets) to do this pretty easily.

```
obj = {'ABC-01': ['aaa',
            'bbb',
            'ccc',
            'ddd'],
       'ABC-02': ['aaa',
            'bbb',
            'ccc',
            'eee']}

unique_items = set()
for key in obj:
    obj[key] = set(obj[key])
    unique_items ^= obj[key]

for key in obj:
    print(key + " contains " + str(obj[key] & unique_items))
```

Output:

```
ABC-01 contains {'ddd'}
ABC-02 contains {'eee'}
```